# how to retrieve blob data from Azure blob in Json format?

Tags: json, azure, json.net, azure-blob-storage

I have stored json data format in azure blob storage,
Now want to retrieve that data from azure blob in the form of json.

I tried like following

```
 //get all blob from contrainer
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connection string");
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("tablesblob");

            foreach (IListBlobItem item in container.ListBlobs(null, false))
            {
                if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
                {
                    CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
                    var ms = new MemoryStream();
                    //blob.DownloadToStream(ms); how to get blob data in the form of JSON?
                }
            }
```

> how to get azure blob data in the form of JSON?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try [`CloudBlockBlob.DownloadText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.downloadtext.aspx) method to download the blob contents as text and then use Json.Net's `JsonConvert` to serialize the string into your customer object. For example, something like the following:

```
            var customerData = blob.DownloadText();
            var customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(customerData);
```

Comment: thanks but how can i convert that json data into Customer object :( because that data is of customer object

Comment: Updated my answer. HTH.

Comment: perfect i was bit confused about to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` directly but you made it simple :) thanks a lot